# ER_PARSE_ERROR on update query with mysql and nodejs

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js

I've looked at other questions similar to this, but I can't seem to find my issue or resolve it. Please help.

What I'm doing is passing input data from client side to the server so it can update a certain row(s) where the ID is matched. I have tried different ways of getting the ID passed to the query, but I am still ending up with ER_PARSE_ERROR.

**Route**

```
app.post('/configuration_materials/editsend/:id', isLoggedIn, materialpricingTable.UPDATEMaterial);
```

**Client/jQuery and ajax function**

```
$(function() {



    $('body').on('click', '.SubmitEditMat', function() {

        var materialIDedit                  = this.id.split('-')[1];


        var clientMtrlApplication       = $('#clientMtrlApplication');
        var clientMtrlType              = $('#clientMtrlType');
        var clientMtrlSpec              = $('#clientMtrlSpec');
        var clientPricePerSheetORFt     = $('#clientPricePerSheetORFt');
        var clientSqFtofSheetORLen      = $('#clientSqFtofSheetORLen');
        var clientWtPerFt               = $('#clientWtPerFt');
        var clientWtPerItem             = $('#clientWtPerItem');
        var clientMtrlPricePerFt        = $('#clientMtrlPricePerFt');
        var clientMtrlPricePerLb        = $('#clientMtrlPricePerLb');
        var clientMtrlPricePerItem      = $('#clientMtrlPricePerItem ');
        var clientLaborHrsPerFt         = $('#clientLaborHrsPerFt');
        var clientLaborHrsPerItem       = $('#clientLaborHrsPerItem');
        var clientNotes                 = $('#clientNotes');

        var divAddMatSuccess            = $('#modifiedModalEditMat');


        $.ajax({
            url: '/configuration_materials/editsend/' + materialIDedit,
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({

                serverMtrlApplication:      clientMtrlApplication.val(),
                serverMtrlType:             clientMtrlType.val(),
                serverMtrlSpec:             clientPricePerSheetORFt.val(),
                serverPricePerSheetORFt:    clientPricePerSheetORFt.val(),
                serverSqFtofSheetORLen:     clientSqFtofSheetORLen.val(),
                serverWtPerFt:              clientWtPerFt.val(),
                serverWtPerItem:            clientWtPerItem.val(),
                serverMtrlPricePerFt:       clientMtrlPricePerFt.val(),
                serverMtrlPricePerLb:       clientMtrlPricePerLb.val(),
                serverMtrlPricePerItem:     clientMtrlPricePerItem.val(),
                serverLaborHrsPerFt:        clientLaborHrsPerFt.val(),
                serverLaborHrsPerItem:      clientLaborHrsPerItem.val(),
                serverNotes:                clientNotes.val()
            }),

            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);


                divAddMatSuccess.html('');

                divAddMatSuccess.append('\
                <div class="alert alert-success">\
                <strong>Success! Updated: </strong> ' + clientMtrlApplication.val() + clientMtrlType.val() + clientMtrlSpec.val() +'\
                </div>\
                ');


            }


        });



    });
});
```

**Server side, materialpricingTable.js with UPDATEMaterial and MySQL query**

// query

```
exports.sqlEditMaterial = "UPDATE generictablenamepleaseignore SET ? where ID = ?;";
```

// UPDATEMaterial function

```
exports.UPDATEMaterial = function (req, res) {
    var weErrored = false;

    var idOfMaterial = req.params.id;


    var post = {

        // NAMEINDATABASE: NAMEONFORM
        Application: req.body.serverMtrlApplication,
        MaterialType: req.body.serverMtrlType,
        MtrlSpecs: req.body.serverMtrlSpec,
        PricePerSheetORFt: req.body.serverPricePerSheetORFt,
        SqFtofSheetORLength: req.body.serverSqFtofSheetORLen,
        WtPerFt: req.body.serverWtPerFt,
        WtPerItem: req.body.serverWtPerItem,
        MtrlPricePerFt: req.body.serverMtrlPricePerFt,
        MtrlPricePerLb: req.body.serverMtrlPricePerLb,
        MtrlPricePerItem: req.body.serverMtrlPricePerItem,
        LaborHrsPerFt: req.body.serverLaborHrsPerFt,
        LaborHrsPerItem: req.body.serverLaborHrsPerItem,
        Notes: req.body.serverNotes
    };

    var sendData = post + idOfMaterial;

    mySqlController.connection.query(exports.sqlEditMaterial, sendData ,
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.code);
                weErrored = true; // setting the error to true, this is used to display a message on the front end

            }

            res.send('Success!');


        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `+` operator with objects (e.g. `post`). In this particular case, you need to pass an array with the two values instead:

```
var sendData = [post, idOfMaterial];
```

Also, the semicolon at the end of the SQL query is unnecessary and is only needed when using a command-line MySQL client (or when executing multiple statements in a single query of course).

Comment: Ahhh. Okay! That worked. Thank you very much for the information.